# Sticky keys problem on Debian

Tags: debian, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

For quite a while now, I have installed on a Dell latitude 3340 a Debian Wheezy distribution which I recently replaced with a Debian Buster. On these two versions of Debian I have encountered (and still encounter) a sticky key problem. 
The way I understand the problem is that when the time interval between key-down and key-up is too short, the sticky key function is activated (as if the key-up was not perceived). 
My main problem is to find information about this bug. I think I can't explain my problem to search engines properly. I found a few topics that are kind of similar, but all very old and not solving my problem. So I hope that asking this question to humans will allow me to be a little better directed, and if possible to find a solution if someone has already encountered a similar problem. Thanks to you.

**Things I’ve noticed :**

- When the affected key is repeated, the trackpad is disabled
  (default behavior).
- The bug is not present in the TTY console ⇒  so it shouldn't be a hardware problem.
- If you disable the key repeat parameter, the letters are no longer repeated (obviously), but the trackpad is still affected.
- Only append on quick touch
- When repeating the key, if I press any key, the normal behaviour resumes
- If I play on rehearsal delay the behaviour is affected (really exactly as if I had physically stayed on the key)

**Environnement :**

PC : Dell latitude 3340

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

xserver-xorg-core   2:1.20.4-1  amd64   Xorg X server - core server

Cinnamon 3.8.8

I'm sure there's other information that might be useful, let me know and I'll insert them.